# Exporting selection to Excel file using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, excel, select

I selected a list of facilities that intersect a polygon using ArcMap, and I want to export them to Excel.

Is there a way to do this without having to export the selection to a shapefile first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Table To Excel](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/table-to-excel.htm):

> Converts a table to a Microsoft Excel file.

Or click one of the grey small boxes to the left in the attribute table - Copy - then paste into excel:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The quickest and easiest I have found is if you are using ArcMap, I would open the attribute table of the facilities that are selected and choose "Export". Make sure "selected records" is chosen, choose the path to export to, make sure the "Save as type" is set to dBASE Table.  This will save a .dbf file that you can open with EXCEL.

[image]

[image]
[image]